# Continuity of $\cos(x)$ at $0^+$

Tags: calculus

Does   $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \cos(x)=1^-$ ?

confused about this specially I know that :

> $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \cos(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^-} \cos(x)=1$

Comment: Yes, $\lim_{x\to 0} \cos(x)=1^-$, note that $\cos(x)\leq 1$!

Comment: @RobertZ It works out in this case, but be careful when finishing a sentence with a mathematical expression and then an exclamation mark. There is potential for misunderstandings.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for your hilarious comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to the original question,

Does   $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \cos(x)=1^-$ ?

I don't understand the source of confusion here.

Yes, the limit is $1$ approached from below, but that's trivial because $1$ is the global maximum of the cosine function for a real domain. It can't very well approach $1$ from above, can it?

So the answer is yes, and quite trivially so.

With regard to the second part,

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \cos(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^-} \cos(x)=1$

Yes, this is true, but again, I don't see why this is confusing. Looking at the plot of $y=\cos x$ about $x=0$ will immediately tell you all you need to know about the behaviour of the function about this point. The statement you wrote just provides justification for the continuity of the function about this point, if you also add the statement $\cos 0 = 1$ (i.e. the function is defined at this point and its value is equal to the limit). Note that the cosine function is continuous throughout its domain.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\cos(x)-\cos(y)=-2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$
It is $$|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|\le \frac{|\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})|}{|\frac{x-y}{2}|}|x-y|$$
This tends to zero if $x$ tends to $y$

Comment: one more hint please . still confused.

Comment: have to dig deep to get the demonstration .

Answer (score 0):

The limit of $\cos x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from above is $1$ approached from below since $\cos x$ has a value $1$ at $0$ and decreases near $0.$